# App's files are Visible in 'Files' app on simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, swift

My app has both of the following info.plist in XCode:

```
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

As far as I can tell, doing this (and actually creating files in the Documents directory) is all that should be required to have the app's folder and files show up in the 'Files' app "On My iPhone".  Eg, as per instructions at:  https://www.appcoda.com/files-app-integration/

I'm obtaining the 'Documents' directory using:

`let docsDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]`

and creating files there using:

```
let baseDestURL = docsDir.appendingPathComponent(dirName)
try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: baseDestURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: tmpURL!, to: baseDestURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName))
```

...and no error is generated by the `try` line, which indicates that it works.

The app does create a folder with some files in it and on the simulator, I can see the app's folder in the 'Files' app under "On My iPhone".  However, on the actual device, the 'Files' app shows no folder for my app in "On My iPhone".

I know that the files are there, because the code in my app displays information that it reads from those files.

Why can't I see them in the 'Files' app on the device?

Comment: Thanks for the unexplained downvote and close vote.  Please tell me what you require to make this question more acceptable rather than unhelpfully just downvoting with no explanation.  I'd like to make the question better, if possible, but I can't do that if I don't know why you think it's a bad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the iPhone fixed it!

I can only guess as to why.  Perhaps iOS had cached the capabilities of an earlier version of the app which did have 'Files' access and perhaps uninstalling and re-installing the app may have also resolved it (certainly just re-installing the app by running from XCode did NOT resolve it.

But simply restarting the iPhone, then opening the 'Files' app showed the app's folder and all the files therein.